# How to store subclass-specific information?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an `abstract class A` and I want it to enforce its subclasses to have `String Title` and `String Description` properties. So if `B extends A`, B is guaranteed to have property Title with a value that's the same across all the instances of B.

If Java permitted static abstract methods (that is, static methods that have to be in every subclass), I'd just write

```
public abstract class A {
    public static abstract String getTitle();
    public static abstract String getDescription();
}
```

The best idea I've come up with so far is to use separate enumeration which stores Title and Description for each subclass. That way I can look through all the `Title`s with a single loop and instantiate a subclass with the title I need (this is the desired behavior). Unfortunately, that way I'll have to change the enum every time I add a subclass. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about mixing static stuff and inheritance. Just calls for trouble.

Instead, you turn to [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

```
abstract class A { 
   public final String getTitle () { return getTitleInternal(); }
   abstract String getTitleInternal();

class B extends A {
   @Override
   String getTitleInternal { maybe return some static value of B }
```

Please note that this is "better" than putting protected fields on class A. The essence of OO and inheritance is about **behavior** (so, you were correct in saying that you want certain methods on your subclass).

EDIT: after reading your comments again; I am tempted to remind you on

a) using interfaces

b) focusing on composition over inheritance

Comment: Thank you. But what if I don't want to instantiate a class before I know its title? Should I rethink my design?

The problem I stuck with is that I let a user choose a subclass. Now I suspect that it wasn't a good decision.

Answer (score 1):

Did you think of using protected fields?

```
public abstract class A {
    protected String title;
    protected String description;
}
```

This way the two fields are visible in any class that extends A.

```
public abstract class B extends A {
        public B(){
            title = ...
            description = ....
        }

    }
```

Comment: I did, and there's two reasons they are not suitable: (1) title and description have to be accessible to the outside world (in fact, this is what I'm trying to enforce) and (2) it would be nice to ensure that the value of title and description does not differ across multiple instances of the same subclass.

Comment: title and description can have getter/setter methods in the abstract class, thus they are 'accessible'. Regarding the multiple instances, I would also use a singleton. But in this case I think @Jägermeister's answer is better.